# how can i navigate between icons in the appBar on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, icons, appbar, flutter-appbar

I am new flutter developer and I would like to browse among these icons in app bar,Any idea?

[image]tmy.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Tab Bar, please check this : https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=r1sQTA_zPog

If you hope to do it with the hard way you can make a button for each icon and in onPressed  add setState with Navigator and modified color

Check ; https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation

Answer (score 1):

You can use like the below code for every icon.

```
IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.add_box),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
          );
        },
      )
```